# sorting in pandas, while alternating between ascending and descending on the same sorting column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I would like to sort a dataframe by a two columns, but one is always ascending, and the other switches between ascending and descending based on the value of the first column. In other words, when the first column increases, the sorting flips from ascending to descending or vise versa.

My motivation for this is that I am trying to sort a set of data that is indexed spatially in a gird into chronological order. The data is measured by snaking upwards, and then back and forth in a grid. I would like to sort ascending by y value, and then go back and forth in the x value whenever the y value increments. I don't know how to so this with `df.sort_values()` or `df.groupby()` as those alter the whole dataframe.

I am trying to sort this

```
X position | Y position | Data
     0            0        '1st'
     0            1        '4th'
     1            0        '2nd'
     1            1        '3rd'
```

Into this

```
X position | Y position | Data
     0            0        '1st'
     1            0        '2nd'
     1            1        '3rd'
     0            1        '4th'
```

Comment: I'm confused. This seems to be `df.sort_values(['Y position', 'X position']))` no?

Comment: That, doesn't quite work because the column 'X position' switches between being sorted by ascending and descending, and to my knowledge you can't pass to boolean values into the parameter ascending=True/False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have found a solution in the meantime...

You could do the following:

```
df = pd.concat(
    [
        sdf.sort_values("X", ascending=i%2)
        for i, (_, sdf) in enumerate(df.sort_values("Y").groupby("Y"), start=1)
    ]
)
```

or

```
def sort(sdf):
    global i
    i += 1
    return sdf.sort_values("X", ascending=i%2)

i = 0
df = df.sort_values("Y").groupby("Y", group_keys=False).apply(sort)
```

Result for

```
df =
   X  Y
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  0  2
3  1  0
4  1  1
5  1  2
```

is

```
   X  Y
0  0  0
3  1  0
4  1  1
1  0  1
2  0  2
5  1  2
```